# Make the X Close button open a new JFrame in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I would like to make it so that when you click the X close button on the top right, a new `JFrame` will appear and the current one will close.

How would I be able to do it?

Comment: Look up WindowListener. You might want to lookup DefaultCloseOperation

Comment: Or use a modal JDialog. But regardless of which route you go, first please read [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636)

Comment: @MadProgrammer could you please tell me with an answer how to use Window Listeners? I can't get it to work.

For example: @ Override
 public void windowOpened(WindowEvent e) {
  System.out.println("Hello world"); 
 }
(I know it's @ Override without the space but I couldn't type it like that because I had already mentioned you)

Comment: Be aware that users typically close a window because they want to exit.  Refusing to let the user leave may annoy them considerably.

Comment: @Hilex23 Please tale the time to research your problem, start with [How to Write Window Listeners](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/windowlistener.html) and the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/awt/event/WindowListener.html), try a few things, if you're still not getting the results you're expecting, post a new question with a [mcve] which demonstrates your attempts

Comment: @VGR I actually wanted to make a "Are you sure you want to exit" JFrame

Comment: Use [JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.desktop/javax/swing/JOptionPane.html#showConfirmDialog(java.awt.Component,java.lang.Object,java.lang.String,int)) for that.

Answer (score 1):

The question is, can another JFrame open automatically when one JFrame closes. As noted in comments, two possible common solutions include use of a WindowListener or use of a modal dialog (one example of which is as mentioned by Chance Hoard, a JOptionPane, which again is *one* solution, but certainly not the *only* solution).

For a WindowListener to work, you can open the new JFrame in the `windowClosed()` method, for example:

```
JFrame frame1 = new JFrame("Frame 1");
frame1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
frame1.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(500, 400)));
frame1.pack();
frame1.setLocationByPlatform(true);
frame1.setVisible(true);

frame1.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowClosed(WindowEvent e) {
        JFrame frame2 = new JFrame("Frame 2");
        frame2.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame2.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(500, 400)));
        frame2.pack();
        frame2.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame2.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

The key here is to set the default close operation to not be `JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE` so as not to close down the JVM after the initial JFrame window has closed. In the window listener's `windowClosed()` method, create and display the 2nd JFrame.

---

To solve this using a modal dialog, I would create the second window, which could be a JFrame, first, to give the dialog an parent application, but then I would write code to display it *after* displaying the modal dialog. This way, it only shows up once the dialog is no longer visible:

```
JFrame frame3 = new JFrame("Frame 3");
frame3.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
frame3.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(500, 400)));
frame3.pack();
frame3.setLocationByPlatform(true);
// don't display this JFrame yet

// create the dialog, passing in the JFrame and making the dialog "modal"
JDialog dialog1 = new JDialog(frame3, "Dialog 1", ModalityType.APPLICATION_MODAL);
dialog1.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
dialog1.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(500, 400)));
dialog1.pack();
dialog1.setLocationRelativeTo(frame3);

// show the dialog first
dialog1.setVisible(true);

// this is called only after the dialog is no longer visible
frame3.setVisible(true);
```

---

Having said all this, I still recommend that you read the [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9554636) link and I recommend avoiding *both* of the above "solutions" and instead recommend that one create and display a single main application window, a JFrame, and instead swap GUI *views*, usually JPanels, by using a CardLayout.